# constraints on constructor parameters

Tags: scala, parameters, constraints

Excuse me, but I'm new to Scala.
I have a abstract class and a concrete class that inherits from the abstract class and implements its fields.

```
abstract class Element {
  var name: String
  var description: String
}

class ConcreteElement (var name: String, var description: String)extends Element
```

Is this right? Yes?
I have many classes that inherit from abstract class Element.
Now I want to put a check on the variable name, that I want to instantiate name only in accordance with certain constraints. Where do I put this control? Obviously in abstract class Element.

In Scala A variable declaration var x: T is equivalent to declarations of a getter function x and a setter function x_=, defined as follows:

```
def x: T
def x_= (y: T): Unit
```

So I decided to declare the variables in this way and posizionere my constraints in the getter method name.

```
abstract class Element {    
def name: String
def name_= (y: String): Unit = {CONSTRAINT}

var description: String
}
```

class ConcreteElement (var name: String, var description: String)extends Element

This reasoning is correct?
ConcreteElement actually implements the fields of Element?

Comment: Do you really need mutable fields (vars) in your context?

Comment: Some fields are of type String other of type Set(something).
I think it is not necessary to use var.
But if I do not use var, how can I set constraints on the method setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `def name_=` works only if it has not been overriden by the sub-class. So I guess you need `final` to prevent it being overriden.

```
abstract class Element {
  protected var _name: String
  final def name: String = _name
  final def name_= (value: String) {
    if (isBadValue(value)) throw new IllegalArgumentException
    _name = value
  }
  var description: String
}
class ConcreteElement (protected var _name: String, var description: String) extends Element
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Excuse me, but maybe I was not very clear.

I have a package with the domain of a model. Consists of abstract and concrete classes.
In another package I want to implement a DSL to instantiate my classes.
Some fields in the domain have the constraint. They can not accept all values.

The solution you have proposed, does not solve my problems.
I inherited _name will not be tested. Right?

In addition, I can use protected if I work in different packages?

Comment: Your `ConcreteElement` must not override `name` and `name_=`, but it may override `_name`. And your other classes must not access `_name`. Instead, they must use `name` and `name_=`.

Comment: Hello,
I'm so sorry, but I can not understand how to override.

All classes that inherit from Element must not override the field "name", they must implement the field: "name" of Element.

Excuse me for the bad English translation

Comment: Hello,
your solution controls the constraints only when a new value is assigned a name. But not when you create a new instance of ConcreteElement.
Example:
Here I have no control:
val C1 = new ConcreteElement ("nameOfC1", "descriptionOfC1")

But here I have control:
C1.name = "otherName"

I would like to control the field name forever. Is there a solution to this problem?
Thank you and excuse me for the inconvenience.